# Why would this swift code still be performing the segue?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a conditional segue set up that will perform the segue set up the following way:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        if PFUser.currentUser() != nil{ //if the user is logged in previously


            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("AlreadySignedIn", sender: self)

            print(PFUser.currentUser()?.username)


        }
```

Even deleting all users from the database (Parse), the segue is still performed. I don't think the problem is with the syntax of this particular code, but does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: what responds to `PFUser.currentUser()` then?  Also, [why are you still using Parse](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/)?

Comment: Hi @MichaelDautermann parse.com expose much of their functionality as open source which called parse-server. parse-server can be deployed to any cloud provider and the big advantage is that you can still use the same app and leverage the same SDK's. You can read more in here: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PFUser.currentUser() is not aware about the users that you have in your DB. 
when you log in to Parse via parse ios SDK. the parse IOS SDK save the currentUser instance on your disk and when you specify PFUser.currentUser() the parse IOS SDK check if the user was logged in before (by checking if it is stored on the disk). if you want that the PFUser.currentUser() will return nil you must call PFUser.logout() function. this function will clear the current logged in user.